# This is my first pygame project and I'm trying to make a space invaders game but my image resizing commands are having no effect

Tags: python, pygame

I've tried:

```
player_width = 90
player_height = 90
pygame.transform.scale(player, (player_width, player_height))
```

and:

```
pygame.transform.rotozoom(enemy, 0, .1)
```

Neither of these commands has the desired effects on the size of my images.

Comment: Sorry for the terrible formatting I don't know how to use this.

Comment: In the code provided, you're not using any code to draw the surface. Is it the full source code?

Comment: Please help us by providing a [minimally reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

The scale method returns a new surface. It does not scale the original.

Try this:

```
player_width = 90 
player_height = 90
player = pygame.transform.scale(player, (player_width, player_height))
```

You can check the documentation here:
https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.scale